# linkedIn api: I can't get language proficiency

Tags: php, json, linkedin-api

I am gathering user information from linkedIn API succesfully. My problem occurs when I want to get the language proficiency level. It is expressed in the documentation (https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields#languages) that language object has a proficiency member, but I don't see it in the response. What might be my mistake? Below is the structure of the language object that came from api:

```
var_dump($user->languages->values[0]);
```

output:

```
object(stdClass)#10 (2) 
{ 
    ["id"]=> int(10) 
    ["language"]=> object(stdClass)#11 (1) 
    { 
        ["name"]=> string(8) "Türkçe" 
    } 
}
```

this is the api call that I make

```
$user = fetch('GET', '/v1/people/~:(firstName,lastName,positions,skills,languages,educations)');
function fetch($method, $resource, $body = '') {
$params = array('oauth2_access_token' => $_SESSION['access_token'],
                'format' => 'json',
          );

$url = 'https://api.linkedin.com' . $resource . '?' . http_build_query($params); 
$context = stream_context_create(
                array('http' => 
                    array('method' => $method,
                    )
                )
            );


$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

$user = json_decode($response); 

return $user;
```

}

Comment: What does your API call look like?

Comment: I edited the question, included the api call

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems that the languages field selector, despite the documentation implying it, does not return proficiency level by default.
Try using the expanded selector for the languages.

```
$user = fetch('GET', '/v1/people/~:(firstName,lastName,positions,skills,languages:(id,language,proficiency),educations)');
```

Unfortunately I have no running API application to test this call in.

Comment: Just tested this using the apigee API development console (https://apigee.com/console/linkedin). It worked for me (my own profile, so r_fullprofile permission).

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your call like this to get the details:

```
"skills:(skill,proficiency,years),languages:(id,language,proficiency)"
```